# What does "Fraudulent copying of software" mean in ISO 27005?

Tags: iso27005

In ISO 27005 Annex C "Examples of typical threats", under "Unauthorized actions", I do not understand the example of "Fraudulent copying of software".

From my point of view this is kind of a "disclosure/information leakage"? I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: Welcome to the community. I guess it would be ways to circumvent software's DRM, licensing systems, cracking the software and depending on where you are - reverse engineering.

Comment: Upon googling "Fraudulent copying of software" there are lots of examples.

Comment: While true @schoeder, almost all results are related to "Software Piracy" but this is already addressed by the "Use of counterfeit or copied software"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fraudulent copying of software is copying software without having the right to do so.

This may be information leakage, for example, if such software is part of the intellectual property of an organisation. It could also mean that the software will be used as a pirated version without license, for example at home. The issue would then be legal compliance.

Comment: Thanks @Ljm !
That gave me another point of view which I didn't count on